# how to concatenate Where clause with Like

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to concatenate `SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause + 'con.BusinessName LIKE ' + '%'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@BusinessName) + '%' + '  AND ';` this line.

I want to result like this `SET @WhereClause= con.BusinessName LIKE  '%Hello%'  AND ';`

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using parameters.  But you need the single quotes:

```
'''%'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), @BusinessName) + '%'''
```

You should also specify the length for `VARCHAR()` in SQL Server.  The default varies by context and debugging problems can be quite hard.

Note:  This will fail if `@BusinessName` has a single quote.  Think:  parameters.

Comment: Thank @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could use `QUOTENAME` function (SQL Server 2008 and above):

`SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + 'con.BusinessName LIKE ' + QUOTENAME('%' + CONVERT(varchar(126), @BusinessName) + '%', '''') + ' AND ';`

With the `QUOTENAME` function you can avoid your code to break when `@BusinessName` contains single quote characters, and eliminate the possibility of SQL injection attacks as well (for example, if `@BusinessName` gets its value directly from an UI, via a query parametar or request body in a web application/APIs, etc.).

The `QUOTENAME` is intended for making valid delimited identifiers in dynamic SQL, but it could be used in your case.

The function accepts `nvarchar(128)` as an input string, and if the `@BusinessName` is longer than 126 characters (128 minus two `%` characters) it will return `NULL`. So, you should take care of that edge case.